# PHP newbie question: return variable with function?

Tags: php, function, recordset

i've been coding asp and was wondering if this is possible in php:

```
$data = getData($isEOF);

function getData($isEOF=false)
{
    // fetching data
    $isEOF = true;
    return $data;
}
```

the function getData will return some data, but i'd like to know - is it possible to also set the $isEOF variable inside the function so that it can be accessed from outside the function?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, if your function expects it to be **passed by reference** :

```
function getData(& $isEOF=false) {

}
```

Note the `&` before the variable's name, in the parameters list of the function.

For more informations, here's the relevant section of the PHP manual : [**Making arguments be passed by reference**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)

And, for a quick demonstration, consider the following portion of code :

```
$value = 'hello';
echo "Initial value : $value<br />";

test($value);
echo "New value : $value<br />";


function test(& $param) {
    $param = 'plop';
}
```

Which will display the following result :

```
Initial value : hello
New value : plop
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the global statement you can use variables in any scope.

```
$data = getData();

function getData()
{
    global $isEOF;

    // fetching data
    $isEOF = true;
    return $data;
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more info.

Comment: Make sure you declare $isEOF before using it as a global.
Ex:  add `$isEOF = false` above `$data = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to pass the variable by reference.

See the example here : http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/functions.arguments.php